# Accessing an object's fields without an active session

Tags: hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 4.0.1.Final.  Is it possible to access an object's fields if that object has been loaded via the org.hibernate.Session.load(Class clazz, Serializable id) method and there is no active session?

I use this code to access an object by id …

```
protected Object find(Class clazz, Serializable id) {
    Object obj = null;
    try {
        startOperation();
        obj = session.load(clazz, id);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        handleException(e);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

but if I have that object without an active session, like with this code …

```
final Organization foundOrg = orgDao.findById(org.getOrganizationId());
System.out.println(foundOrg.getName());
```

I get this error on the "System.out" line …

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    at org.myco.myproject.orgsclient.model.Organization_$$_javassist_0.getName(Organization_$$_javassist_0.java)
    at org.myco.myproject.orgsclient.dao.OrganizationDAOTest.testInsertSchool(OrganizationDAOTest.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `session.get(Class, Serializable)` instead of `session.load(Class, Serializable)`

Load will return a proxy to the object, this object is loaded from the database when you first access a property on the proxy. If you use `session.get()` you're guaranteed to get a fully initialized object back.

The other difference between load and get is the result of an object not being found. Get will return null whereas load will always return a proxy. This proxy will throw an exception when a property is accessed.

Comment: +1, and you're also guaranteed to get null rather than a proxy if the object doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: Thanks, I have added this to my answer.

Comment: load() won't throw an exception. It will return a proxy, and you will get an exception wnen calling any method of the proxy if the object doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Always good to learn something new.